# Creating a URL array for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that uses data from an XML file. It currently call the file like this.

```
var xmlFile = 'xml/warnings.xml';
```

Then parse the variable for the data like so.

```
 downloadUrl(xmlFile, function(data) {
```

What I would like to know is if it is possible and if so what is the correct way to create a variable with multiple URLs something like this...

```
var xmlFile = 'xml/file1.xml,xml/file2.xmlxml/file3.xmlxml/file4.xml';
```

Now before someone asks why. Well, the data I need is spread across several XML feeds from the same place. So the formats are exactly the same and will be parsed exactly as if I was just using one XML so there wouldn't be any conflicts.

Comment: [example of loading an array of URLs](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_easterngeek_linkto.html), uses the geoxml3 third party KML parser, which I don't know that you want, but exhibits the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing it entirely with JS, then you'd have to make a separate request for each XML file. I think the better approach would be to use your server as a proxy - fire one AJAX request off to your server which calls a function that goes and grabs (curl?) all these files and sends them back down to you already processed.

Comment: I have previously tried separate requests and that doesn't work. I currently use cron with wget to grab the feeds and store them locally on my server as you can't parsed a feed directly in Google Maps. Another option was to merger all the XML feeds stored locally but, that could be a lot of work. So wanted to investigate this option first as it would be the easiest.

Comment: If separate requests "didn't work" it's because it wasn't implemented correctly. You can definitely do it with separate requests, but the more efficient option is to have your server pre-process the XML files for you so the client's browser only has to deal with processing the data it actually needs.

Comment: Yes I am aware it wasn't implemented correctly. That is why I asked in my original post "What I would like to know is if it is possible and if so what is the correct way to create a variable with multiple URLs". How is the proper way to implement this? As I stated in my last response. My server already pre-processes the XML feeds because Google Maps doesn't allow you parse direct feeds.